# Renaming a release in VSTS Release Management

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to rename a release that’s currently in progress or already completed?

I tried renaming the release with the syntax below but it always throws an error saying "Adding or deleting stages from the release is not allowed"

```
var releases = releaseClient.GetReleasesAsync(definitionId: 100, searchtext: "OldReleaseName").Result;

var release = release.FirstOrDefault();
release.Name = "new release name";

releaseClient.UpdateReleaseAsync(release, "projectName", release.Id).Wait();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to rename a release.

The error seen in this particular case is because of the fact that a the GetReleases API returns a shallow copy of the release, while the UpdateRelease API accepts the full blown object.

To fix the error in the code above, we would also need to a call to GetRelease API to load the complete release object and use that in the Update call.

```
var releases = releaseClient.GetReleasesAsync(definitionId: 100, searchtext: "OldReleaseName").Result;

var release = release.FirstOrDefault();

// Add a null check here? This is to load the complete release object.
release = releaseClient.GetReleaseAsync("projectName", release.Id).Result;

release.Name = "new release name";

releaseClient.UpdateReleaseAsync(release, "projectName", release.Id).Wait();
```